# Lookup by coordinates mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a record in mysql db with latitude and longitude data, however when I try to select records by using the lat or long I get no results back.

If I had this in my db:

```
latitude: -99.7525, longitude: 22.9888
```

When I do this :

```
SELECT `addresses`.* FROM `addresses` WHERE `addresses`.`latitude` = -99.7525
```

Even when I see this `latitude` when I select the record using primary key. What is going on here?

Odd stuff:

```
select * from addresses where longitude = (
  SELECT longitude FROM addresses WHERE id = 490
)
```

results in :

```
'1','99.7525','27.9888', MEX','2'
```

However :

```
select * from addresses where longitude = 27.9888
```

No results.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the value `-99.7525` in your database?

Comment: check datatype of latitude. if it is string then `latitude` = '-99.7525'

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't know what to think please check my update. Mukesh no its not a string I checked